# How can I work node functions in sequence, when the functions are different node projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, microservices

I have 3 node different projects(services). This is structure.

```
BIG SERVICE
  -service_1
    -start.js
  -service_2
    -start.js
  -service_3
    -start.js
  -big_start.js
```

I want,that when I run big_start.js node file,first work service_1->start.js if everything is OK, second work service_2->start.js,if everything is OK,third work service_3-> start.js.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use `async/await` then it should be relatively easy to model them in series:

```
async awaitChain() {
   try {
     const result1 = await startService1();

     const result2 = await startService2();
     ...
     const result3 = await startService3();
     ...
   catch (err) {
     // handle error
   }
   // all is well each has been initialized in series
   return await bigStart();
}
```

This pattern could be abstracted and generalized to execute any number of async functions serially, and bluebird has an [`each`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) primitive that should do exactly this.